# System.Threading.Tasks does not contain method Wait();?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wait

enter code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace Threeeead
{
 class ThreadDemo
 {      
    public void Print1(Object obj1)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("1");
        }
    }
    public void Print2()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write("2");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        ThreadDemo objDemo= new ThreadDemo();

       // Thread firstThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(objDemo.Print1));
        //firstThread.Start();

       Thread secondThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(objDemo.Print2));
       secondThread.Start();

        Thread thirdThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart (delegate()
        {
            while(true)
            Console.Write("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        }));

       thirdThread.Start();

       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(objDemo.Print1));

      // ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(objDemo.Print2));


       secondThread.Wait();
```

Hi, my question is, why in last line I have error which said: 
"Error  1   'System.Threading.Thread' does not contain a definition for 'Wait' and no extension method 'Wait' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Thread' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It looks like, this method does not be included in Sys.Thr.Task. namespace.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Thread` is not `Task`.

Comment: When you Google that compiler error you'll find the solution. This message always means the same thing regardless of the type involved. And the message clearly tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `Task.Wait()` with `Thread.Join()`.